# WordPress OrderBY on post_meta value

Tags: php, wordpress

I have post in which their are two meta keys. i.e start_year and end_year

start_year and end_year both are optional field. In case if they are empty I have stored like 0000.
[image]
I want to fetch record like that:

1. Empty end_year comes first
2. sort by end_year and start_year in desc.

Comment: “I want” is not a question, and this site not a code-writing service. You need to explain what you have tried already, and what the specific problem with it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read `wp_query` documentaion

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'end_year' =>    array(
            'key'     => 'end_year',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
        'start_year' =>    array(
            'key'     => 'end_year',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        )
    ),
    'orderby'  => array( 'start_year' => 'DESC', 'end_year' => 'DESC' )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: is this work because , I required end_year with empty data first and after that in descending order with end_year and start_year